# Prove :insufficient conditions on topology generated by a basis cause it to fail

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation

This theorem deals with conditions that guarantee us that $\mathfrak{B*}$ is a topology on X
and that $\mathfrak{B*}$ is such that $\mathfrak{B*}$ is also a topology on X.

**Theorem**

Let B be the collection of all closed intervals on the real line.Show that $\mathfrak{B*}$
,the collection of all possible unions of
elements of B ,together with the empty set
is *not* a topology on **R**

**Proof**

(Edited)
By this point, a topology is defined by open  sets so

A.1) X and $0$ opened

A.2)Intersection of arbitrary opened
sets are opened

A.3) The union of a finite number of opened sets is opened

So we have to show B fails. If A.3 fails,B fails.

$\mathfrak{B*}$=$\bigcup${x}$\cup${0} is neither open or closed so describing A.3 will fail

Not to sure how to describe an interval
from here.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: A topology is described by *open* sets (if you use a base). Don't be misled by the fact that we're using closed intervals...

Comment: Ok. The theorem assumes that and l have to show B fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take it to mean that closed interval is a non-trivial one, so that $[x,x] = \{x\}$ is excluded (these *do* form a base, for the discrete topology, if we include them). So only $[a,b]$ with $a < b$ are used.

Then consider $[0,1] \cap [1,2]= \{1\}$ which is a finite intersection of non-trivial closed intervals but is *not* writable as a union of such intervals (as it's a finite set, e.g.).

Comment: Uh so a closed interval can be written